# How to find all tokens that implements a specific contract

Tags: contract-development, addresses, filters

I'm trying to filter all the Tokens that implement a specific contract for a specific public address.

I'm using web3 / metamask app. I'm trying to do it on via

```
var options = { 
....
//address: "....",
//???
};

var filter = web3.eth.filter(options);

web3.eth.filter(options, function(error, result){
if (!error)
   console.log(result);
});
```

My goal is to operate with ERC721 tokens, so to access to the metadata of the single Token.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You're looking for all token contracts of a specific type (eg. ERC20) that have a balance for a specific address? You could [search for contracts with similar code on Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/find-similiar-contracts), then check those contracts for the address.

Comment: My goal is to operate with contracts that implements ERC721 specifications, so tokens in which every contract has specific metadata. For instance: all the CryptoKitties a user has w/o using third party apis but just using the web3js stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Solidity or EVM bytecode does not have support for "interface declarations" akin to Java interfaces or some other languages.

The only to know which contracts implement a certain interface is to maintain a database of such contract address (based on user submissions, etc.).